# Chef's nodejs cookbook failing to install package.json

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a node (Ubuntu 16, Laravel 5.2, Php 7, Nginx) which I've configured using a default recipe:

```
package 'git'
package 'php'
package 'composer'
include_recipe 'nodejs'
include_recipe 'nodejs::npm'

nodejs_npm 'gulp'
...
more commands
...
```

That default recipe works fine. When I get to my deploy recipe though, it fails every time when trying to use the nodejs_npm service to install from package.json.

```
nodejs_npm 'package.json' do
  path    /path/to/app/dir
  json    true
  user    'ubuntu'
  options ['--dependencies', '--silent']
end
```

I'm following their outline on their [github](https://github.com/redguide/nodejs) page so I'm not sure what's going on but this is the message and compiled resource that i get back:

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'nodejs_npm[package.json]'
================================================================================
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
execute[install NPM package package.json] (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/nodejs/providers/npm.rb line 6) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received ''
---- Begin output of npm install  --dependencies  ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@1.0.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
---- End output of npm install  --dependencies  ----
Ran npm install  --dependencies  returned 


Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/my-cookbook/recipes/deploy.rb:51:in `from_file'
nodejs_npm("package.json") do
  action [:install]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  default_guard_interpreter :default
  declared_type :nodejs_npm
  cookbook_name "my-cookbook"
  recipe_name "deploy"
  path "/path/to/app/dir"
  json true
  user "ubuntu"
  options ["--dependencies", "--silent"]
  package "package.json"
end
```

Comment: Please add the complete error message.

Comment: @StephenKing I've updated the question with more of the error message

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of the full error message I'll just point out that [poise-javascript](https://github.com/poise/poise-javascript) has a resource for this specifically: `npm_install`. You might also want to check out application_javascript which has more stuff for deploying node apps, which it sounds like you're trying to do.

https://github.com/poise/application_examples/blob/master/recipes/todo_express.rb shows an example of using both of those to deploy a simple Express app. Might be simpler than what you have now.

Comment: I'll give it a look when i have time. I haven't been too pleased with the one im using.

Comment: this is cool, but how do i pass options? My chef recipe seems to be stopping on the npm install portion because of a stderr message out put by node. I want to pass `--silent`

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't an options property, but there probably should be one. That said, stderr shouldn't be failing the run, can you please include the output from Chef in your question?